# VS code indentation when copying and pasting is messed up

Tags: indentation, visual-studio-code

Why is the indentation almost always messed up when copying and pasting code in VScode?

For example:

**Copying**:

[image: Copy Example]

**Pasting**:

[image: Pasting example]

**Another example**:

[image: copy example]

[image: paste example]

And it's sometimes even more messed up.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm new to VSCode, but do you have `"editor.formatOnPaste": true`?

Comment: where can I check?

Comment: This seems more like a question to the OP than an answer in its current format.

Comment: Oh I found it, it behaves like Visual Studio editor now as it should. Nice. I don't understand why it's not true by default.

Comment: @shinzou.. I know it is late but you can find that in Settings (Ctrl + , ). And there you will find a checkbox - "Format On Paste". Just uncheck it. And things will work fine on Copy paste.

Comment: regardless of whether formatOnPaste is true or not, VSCode messes up the indentation for me regardless when I paste code